# Word for amount of time to be subtracted

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What might be a word or short phrase for a period of time intended to be subtracted from a given date?

> The beginning of the term is calculated by subtracting the _____ from the current date."

Comment: You've got a lot of answers but the sentence makes no sense to me. The current date is always changing (every day in fact) so how can you calculate the beginning of term from it? Please can you explain exactly what  the whole sentence is supposed to mean. Thanks

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to keep it generic. Maybe better stated, I'm documenting a couple business processes where a second date is calculated by removing the ____ from an already given date. A simplified example might be a automated report that can be run for "one day past until present", "one week past until present", etc

Comment: Well, I suppose you calculate the start date of a process by subtracting its *duration* from its end-date. So I agree with with the answer by michael.hor,

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of anything is calculated by subtracting the **time (or period) elapsed** from the current time. If you want a single-word term, consider **duration**:

> **duration**
>   1. the length of time something continues or exists.
>
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/duration)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for 'time span', which would describe a period of time between two events.

> "The beginning of the term is calculated by subtracting the time span from the current date"

Answer (score 0):

I might use **interval.**

> **interval**
>
> https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/interval
>
> a definite length of time marked off by two instants

Not entirely spelled out by this definition is that it is often used to measure jumps in time.